# What version level will npm update vs npm install pick?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-update

I have published a global npm module in the following versions:

```
0.0.1
0.0.2
1.0.0
```

First, I installed the npm module globally in version `0.0.1`, then I ran `npm update -g mymodule`.

- Why did it update to `0.0.2` instead of `1.0.0`?
- When I ran `npm install -g mymodule` again it updated to version `1.0.0`. Why is that?

Do `npm update -g` and `npm install -g` update different version levels?